# How to redirect to another page using flutter provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

How to redirect to another page automatically after a delay in flutter using provider state management?

Answer (score 0):

Hi would you be able to give any more info? What app are you building and what kind of result are you expecting? What code have you come up with at the moment?

With the limited info i have , i came across this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) , I really hope it helps. Let me know if you still needing help.

Comment: I need to build a splashscreen

Answer (score 0):

So i found the answer on another website, i'm wanting try it out myself but the code can be found [here](https://medium.com/swlh/create-a-splash-screen-with-bloc-in-flutter-c495ef22b1be)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but here you use the statefulwidget, I need provider statemanagement instead of statefulwidget. Can we do the same using the provider statemanagement?

Comment: i'll look into it and revert back

Comment: i edited my answer and put the link to the answer, let me know if it helps you